# Android Wheel day and time picker get values

Tags: android, button, textview, android-wheel

Hi All I am using Wheel lib in app, I want to show date and time in Toast when I click button. How can I do it??

This is code of the example where I just show date and time in wheel but I want to get and show date and time in Toast.

```
public class Time2Activity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.time2_layout);

    final WheelView hours = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
    NumericWheelAdapter hourAdapter = new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 23);
    hourAdapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_item);
    hourAdapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
    hours.setViewAdapter(hourAdapter);

    final WheelView mins = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.mins);
    NumericWheelAdapter minAdapter = new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 59, "%02d");
    minAdapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_item);
    minAdapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
    mins.setViewAdapter(minAdapter);
    mins.setCyclic(true);

    final WheelView ampm = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.ampm);
    ArrayWheelAdapter<String> ampmAdapter =
        new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, new String[] {"AM", "PM"});
    ampmAdapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_item);
    ampmAdapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
    ampm.setViewAdapter(ampmAdapter);

    // set current time
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
    hours.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    mins.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    ampm.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

    final WheelView day = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.day);
    day.setViewAdapter(new DayArrayAdapter(this, calendar));        
}

/**
 * Day adapter
 *
 */
private class DayArrayAdapter extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {
    // Count of days to be shown
    private final int daysCount = 20;

    // Calendar
    Calendar calendar;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    protected DayArrayAdapter(Context context, Calendar calendar) {
        super(context, R.layout.time2_day, NO_RESOURCE);
        this.calendar = calendar;

        setItemTextResource(R.id.time2_monthday);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int day = -daysCount/2 + index;
        Calendar newCalendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        newCalendar.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);

        View view = super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
        TextView weekday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2_weekday);
        if (day == 0) {
            weekday.setText("");
        } else {
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            weekday.setText(format.format(newCalendar.getTime()));
        }

        TextView monthday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2_monthday);
        if (day == 0) {
            monthday.setText("Today");
            monthday.setTextColor(0xFF0000F0);
        } else {
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
            monthday.setText(format.format(newCalendar.getTime()));
            monthday.setTextColor(0xFF111111);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return daysCount + 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi which library is used here for wheel view?? I want to make same layout..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Click Button.

```
    public void onClickButtonSelect(View v){
        int AMPM = ampm.getCurrentItem();
            String AMOrPM;
            if (AMPM == 0){
                AMOrPM = "AM";
            }else{
                AMOrPM = "PM";
            }
            String hoursString = Integer.toString(hours.getCurrentItem());
            String minutesString = Integer.toString(mins.getCurrentItem());
            int day = -10/2 + day1.getCurrentItem();
            Calendar newCalendar = (Calendar) calendar1.clone();
            newCalendar.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), format.format(newCalendar.getTime()).toString() + "-" + hoursString + "-" + minutesString + "-" + AMOrPM, 6000).show();

}
```